# Create three Cascading Dropdown Lists with Ajax in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have **three** dropdown list each dependent on previous one.

How it is possible by using MicrosoftAjax & web services?

I also want selected value in Edit view.

I have seen [tip41](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx) of stephen walther.

But i have error on each view i.e.

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("--Select Make--", "Makes") %>
```

that CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and no extension method 'DropDownList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So what would be reason? i am using MVC 1.0.

Comment: same scenario but with jQuery can be done using AjaxDropdown from here: http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the name/option label turned around.  You might also want to try using the signature with the value parameter in it.  I'm not sure why you were having a compile problem, however, since there is a version of the extension that takes two string parameters.  [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) can be found at MSDN.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList( "Makes",
                       "--Select Make--" ) %>
```

OR

```
<%= Html.DropDownList( "Makes",
                       (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Makes"],
                       "--Select Make--" ) %>
```

For cascading dropdowns, you might want to use jQuery instead and get JSON key-value pairs for the next menu based on the selection in the first one.  Add an onChange handler to the selects and do an AJAX get/post to an action in your controller to get the new values.  I construct a list of key value pairs and return that in a JsonResult.  In the success handler of the ajax query, I take that result and replace the contents of the appropriate select with new options using the returned JSON.